# Не отображаются поля формы в админке Django

Tags: django, django-admin

Создал в файле models.py класс:

```
class Useful(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, verbose_name=u'Дата публикации')
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u'URL')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name=u'Заголовок')
    text = RichTextField(config_name='htmld')
    short = RichTextField(config_name='htmld', verbose_name=u'Коротко', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name=u'статью'
        verbose_name_plural=u'полезная информация'
```

Прописал в файле admin.py:

```
class UsefulAdmin(FrontendEditableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'pub_date', 'short')
    fields = ['pub_date', 'slug', 'title', 'text', 'short']
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}

    # Specify name of sortable property
    sortable = 'order'

admin.site.register(Useful, UsefulAdmin)
```

В админке появился раздел Полезная информация, но добавить новую запись не могу. Нет никаких полей.
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй убрать наследование от FrontendEditableAdminMixin

Comment: Пишите более развернутые ответы. Приложите может пример какой.